# Numpy array in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I want to make a function using numpy arrays as arguments.

I have the following code:

```
def Q_aux(j,theta,phi,cm,binom):  

    suma = 0.0 + 0.0j    

    for m in range(-j,j+1):
        for n in range (-j,j+1):
            suma += cm[j+m] * cm[j+n] * sp.sqrt(binom[j+m]*binom[j+n]) * pow(sp.tan(theta/2.0), 2*j+m+n) * cmt.polar(phi*(n-m))

    return suma / pow(1+pow(sp.tan(theta/2.0),2.0), 4.0*j)
```

Where both `binom` and `cm` are one-dimensional arrays. I've checked that I can access (and operate with) its elements using `cm[4]` for example. `sp` and `cmt` are SciPy and Cmath, respectively.

That function, however, gives me the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'complex' and 'tuple'
```

Why this error? How can I avoid it? I've readed a lot of things on Internet and I really don't know what to do with this.

Comment: can you give us a minimal reproducible code example?

Comment: Hint: what's the output type of `cmt.polar`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks. In C++ is polar for complex written as complex exponential, but in Python the command I want is rect. That solved the error :D

Comment: Yes, `rect` is a bit misnamed, really: it's not converting polar coordinates to rectangular coordinates - it's converting polar coordinates to a complex number (which just *happens* to be stored and represented in terms of rectangular coordinates).  `from_polar` might have been a better name.